# RxFrameNtf, TxFrameNtf and Ntf.data in unetpy

Tags: unetstack

I am using Unetstack software along with Unetpy. I wish to retrieve transmit and recieve notifications when I run .py file which imports Unetpy python library. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/blob/master/contrib/Unet-Python-API/python-gateway-tutorial.ipynb)

I am successfully able to connect to the localhost and print values like phy.MTU and so on. When I transmit a packet I also receive a reply saying AGREE on the command prompt.[output_of_my_script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuq8w.png)
[image]
  [my_script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDCio.png)

[image]
Can you please help me in receiving Txframentf and rxframentf along with data payload.

I have made changes posted in bug reports suggested in [this link](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/issues/4)even.
Please guide me on how to print notifications for rxframe and txframe.
Thank you``

Answer (score 4):

Your script is fine until the last line:

```
print(phy << org_arl_unet_phy.TxFrameNtf())
```

Here you are trying to send a `TxFrameNtf` to the physical agent. This does not make sense, as it is the physical agent who sends you such a notification when a transmission is completed.

By the time you reach this line, you should have already received the notification as `txntf` as long as the transmission was completed within 5 seconds (`timeout=5000`). To print out the notification, all you need to do is:

```
print(txntf)
```

I just tested this against the `3-node-network.groovy` sample. I am using `unetpy-1.3b5` and `fjagepy-1.4.2b3`. Here's the modified code:

```
from unetpy import *
modem = UnetGateway('localhost', 1102)
phy = modem.agentForService(Services.PHYSICAL)
print(phy.MTU)
print(phy.basebandRate)
print(phy << org_arl_unet_phy.TxFrameReq(to=3, data=[1,2,3,4]))
txntf = modem.receive(timeout=5000)
print(txntf)
```

and the output:

```
16
4096
AGREE
TxFrameNtf:INFORM[type:1]
```

You can see that the `TxFrameNtf` is correctly received.

For reception, you need to subscribe to the agent's notifications and then receive a frame:

```
modem.subscribe(phy)
rxntf = modem.receive(org_arl_unet_phy.RxFrameNtf, timeout=5000)
print(rxntf)
```

Assuming you receive a frame within the 5 second timeout specified (in this example, on node 3), this should print out something like:

```
RxFrameNtf:INFORM[type:CONTROL from:1 to:3 protocol:0 rxTime:34587658 (4 bytes)]
```

Comment: can you share the link where i can download  a unetpy version which has a unetpy version updated with all these bugs?                                                                                Also please share with me the syntax to print RxFrameNtf and the Ntf.data values on the other node which has received these packets.

Comment: print(phy << org_arl_unet_phy.RxFrameNtf(type = Physical.CONTROL)) I tried with this code to test for RxFrameNtf, I have been getting none all the time. Also with print(phy<<org_arl_unet_phy.RangeReq(to=3)) ==> NOT UNDERSTOOD kindly help me

Comment: The latest `unetpy` version (1.3b5) is released and available via pip. I've edited the response above to show what you get in this version, and to add an example for `RxFrameNtf`. Essentially `RxFrameNtf` is sent by the physical agent and you simply receive it (don't send it using `<<`). For `RangeReq`, you should be sending it to the ranging agent (which you can find using `modem.agentForService(Services.RANGING)`).

Answer (score 1):

You sent a datagram through some agent that supports the DATAGRAM service. There may be many agents that support this service (not just the physical layer). In any case, that datagram would be received on a different node, and so you wouldn't expect to receive `DatagramNtf` on the transmitting node.

The `RangeReq` should yield a `RangeNtf` if successful, but that might take more than the default receive timeout of 1 second, depending on how far node 2 is. So you might want to try a longer receive timeout to see if you get your notification.

To access the data from payload from the `rxntf`, you can try `print(rxntf.data)`.